# CMake: creating object and executable inplace

Tags: cmake, dependencies

I have the following setup:

```
data/
  Makefile
src/
  main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

The `data/Makefile` creates a file `data/file` via the `all` target.

The `src/main.cpp` needs to read `data/file`, e.g.

```
// src/main.cpp
...
      auto is = std::ifstream{"data/file"};
...
```

How can I specify that the executable target for `src/main.cpp` should depend on the output of `data/Makefile`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) for `add_custom_target` states

> Adds a target with the given name that executes the given commands.
> The target has no output file and is always considered out of date even if the commands try to create a file with the name of the target.
> Use the `add_custom_command()` command to generate a file with dependencies.
> By default nothing depends on the custom target.
> Use the `add_dependencies()` command to add dependencies to or from other targets.

Using that hint I found the following way to work:

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt`

```
# CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(data)
add_executable(my_exec src/main.cpp)
add_dependencies(my_exec data_files)
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` in `data/`

```
# data/CMakeLists.txt
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file
                   COMMAND make all
                   DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Makefile 
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
                   )
add_custom_target(data_files
                  DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file)
```